# is there a way to include sub fields with full text search?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have a class

```
public class A {
    public string AName;
    public string BName;
    public string CName;
    public string DName;
    //some nested classes, etc..
}
```

Lets say I have a sub field of AName named "test1" which uses another analyzer and when I populate documents into elasticsearch index, everything is ok.

When I do term based query I can search AName.test1 and result is ok too. Lets say I have some more sub fields of other properties.

Now, I want to use full text search and want to be able to search against these sub fields too along properties themselves.

Is it possible? If it is how can I achieve that with C# client NEST?

BTW if it is unclear or seemed like I didn't effort, it is because of my poor english. I spend 2 days to find out but I couldn't find out how to do it or I don't know if it is even possible.

I'm an elasticsearch newbie, I'm consuming most of my time in elasticsearch's documentation these days to figure out what is the way of doing things efficiently, so I could do a search against fields but I sense that it would be more efficient if I could use full text search but I could be wrong thinking like that. Again, I'm a newbie.

Thank you.

**EDIT 1:**

I changed my search query to search in sub fields instead of property values but to do so I had to use Fields method of Query and I guess I couldn't make it work for nested property sub fields.

**Let me give you an example:**
Lets say I'm searching "**bordo esarp**" and "**esarp**" exists in name.sanalyzed subfield and "**bordo**" exists in name.sanalyzed of one of the documents in a nested property (Nested property: 'props', and its property is 'name.sanalyzed').

I'm using operator "**AND**" to make sure I have only the results which have both words (**"bordo" + "esarp"**).

I have a document to match but query has no result.

To make sure my query works at least partially, I changed my querystring to "**esarp**" and I got results of documents which have "esarp" in name.sanalyzed.

When I did the same query with "**bordo**" (which exists in a nested property's property's sub field) I have no results, so I think I write the query wrong.

My query is:

```
q &= Query<ProductModel>.QueryString(t => t
    .Query(Keyword)
    .DefaultOperator(Nest.Operator.And)
    .Fields(u=>u
    .Field(z=>z.ProductCode.Suffix("sanalyzed"))
    .Field(z=>z.ProductName.Suffix("sanalyzed"))
    .Field(z=>z._CategoryModel.CategoryName.Suffix("sanalyzed"))
    .Field(z=>z.Brand.BrandName.Suffix("sanalyzed"))
    .Field(z=>z.UnionProperties.First().Name.Suffix("sanalyzed"))
    .Field(z=>z.UnionProperties.First().Options.First().Name.Suffix("sanalyzed"))
));
```

I have one more question: I have lots of property called "Name" in different classes. Should I provide them name as a attribute option to make a difference? Does it effect anything?

**EDIT 2:**

```
...
.Map<Yaziylabir.Extensions.TagManagement.Models.TagModel>(m => m.AutoMap().Properties(p => p
    .String(s => s
    .Name(n => n.Tag).Analyzer("sanalyze")))))
.Settings(s => s
    .Analysis(ans => ans
        .Analyzers(anl => anl
            .Custom("sanalyze", c => c
                .Tokenizer("standard")
                .Filters("lowercase", "asciifolding")))));
```

And search is done like:

```
q &= Query<ProductModel>.QueryString(t => t.Query(Keyword).Analyzer("sanalyze"));
```

It doesn't seem to work again. I'm trying to search eşarp or esarp which exists on productname but no results. If I search bordo which doesn't have any dialitic character, it works and gets results.

What do I miss?

**EDIT 3:**

I checked what terms indexed with a query with curl for productName field and the indexed terms are ok.

```
 curl 'http://localhost:9200/bygulay/product/_search?pretty' -d '{"query":{"match_all":{}},"script_fields":{"terms":{"script":"doc[field].values","params":{"field":"productName"}}}}'
```

**Result sample:**

"terms" : [ "6821230", "cardin", "esarp", "ipek", "krep", "pierre", "saten" ]

sanalyze analyzer works. How do I know? productName contains "Eşarp" as value and with sanalyze analyzer it saved as "esarp".

So I think my query is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can search across sub-fields/multi_fields with NEST - [take a look at the Property Inference documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/property-inference.html).

You can use a string to refer to the sub field

```
client.Search<Project>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Match(m => m
            .Field("field.subfield")
            .Query("the query")
        )
    )
);
```

You can also use the `.Suffix()` extension method in conjunction with an expression

```
client.Search<Project>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Match(m => m
            .Field(f => f.Field.Suffix("subfield"))
            .Query("the query")
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: I'm going to try the field.suffix way. Thank you again @RussCam.

Comment: @zokkan no problem :)

Comment: I understand your answer wrong I guess. I want to be able to do a search on 'subfield' suffix of all properties wıth that suffıx avaılable without need to write every property separately. There is a QuoteFieldSuffix extension method but I don't know if it is what I'm searching for.

Comment: You could introduce an attribute to mark properties that are mapped as multi_field, then use `.AppendSuffix()` to apply the same subfield name to a collection of member expressions that target those properties - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/property-inference.html#_appending_suffixes_to_a_lambda_expression

Comment: Now, I'm trying something different. I'm not using subfields but I'm trying to analyze the string properties with a analyzer called "sanalyze" instead of default analyzer and then search them with full text search with sanalyze analyzer.

It doesn't seem to work but I guess I do something wrong because I think logic is valid.

What I miss here on EDIT 2?

Comment: @zokkan Does the mapping reflect the analyzer change? You need to either close the index, update the settings then open the index again, or maybe easier, delete and recreate the index to make a change to analysis.

Comment: I did delete - recreate - index and I have everything updated by this operation. But it doesn't work. I don't know why. :-)

Comment: BTW, do you think filters of my analyzer is ok? do I need anything else to achive what I want? Basicly I only want to be able to search with or without dialitics and find results contains with or without dialitics.

Comment: This is best asked as a separate question; the original question is about how to use sub-fields with full-text search, which has been answered.